# Firebase Login as other user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The purpose is to let the admin login as a normal user and be able to see the same things that user sees.

Is there any way to achieve that in Firebase?

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I need something like this!

Comment: @Marco At the time I asked this question, I needed a dedicated server to generate a custom auth token like Frank's answer. That token should contain the user id you want to access on behalf of. 
Now with Firebase Cloud Functions it should be easier since you don't need a dedicated server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without either knowing the credentials of that user or building something custom for it.

The first thing that comes to mind for a custom solution would be to have a [server that mints custom auth tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) where the `auth.uid` property is set to the `uid` of the impersonated user.

Comment: Is this still true in 2020, even when using the email sign-in method for auth? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can of course log in as the other user by entering their credentials. But aside from that the only option is to mint a custom token with the target user's UID using an Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification and fast response. Firebase is an amazing product, and the free auth tier is insanely generous.

Comment: The link in the answer seems outdated now? Is this the link you want to share: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?

Comment: Thanks Crashalot. I updated the age-old link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

server side (cloud functions)

```
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.impersonate = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const userId = 'aMYQ6ozkaHUsffff3gIyilg5wk1';
            const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId);
            return res.status(200).send({ data: { token } });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(400).send({ data: {} })
        }
    })
});
```

client side:

```
async function impersonate() {
    const { token } = await api.post('impersonate');
    await auth().signInWithCustomToken(auth, token);
}
```